# Is this annotation on the array or on the element type the array?

Tags: java, annotations

Look at this simple code.

```
try (@Foo Stream<@Bar Baz> foo = blabla) { }
```

We know that `@Bar` is annotating `Baz`, and `@Foo` is annotating `Stream` (I've written a similar example [here, compile it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBBTsMwEEX3PsUsEwS@QKGKaY2o5LZREpBYVSYxlYNjR45TVFU5e5iAqFpWHr//Z/w9tTzIO9cqW1ef46ib1vkANUJqpN1Taa0LMmhn6c2MXMp90GZiJFm6sm@UDaoiSaYCVmiPzlXqjC6PdCFYnsckKaTfqxCduFFTU3FsFV3z4nm7vIVL9rTi4h9KWcbQyrNrLLYLJnavLFuxR8GvteIt5buXnA/4ssaI/kOWCjYubHpj4AQwEFIa2XWwltoiaPt3jAvd9OkSDk5X0KAS5cFr3AelGL@L0Zj8DRG6C/fn269vjgOms4MHsOoLmPfy@GOcR/EMBhjG8Rs)).

But what about this code?

```
void whatever(@Foo String[] args) { }
```

Here we have a `String[]` annotated with `@Foo` (whatever the annotation is, it's not important for this question).

My question is, **is `@Foo` annotated on `String` or `String[]`?**

It's quite important to determine the target of the annotation, since sometimes we use annotations like `@NotNull` to represent nullabilities of a type, and `@NotNull List<String>` means a list which is never null is containing some possibly null strings; `List<@NotNull String>` represents a list which is possibly null but the members are never null.

A possible use case: I need a `@NotNull` to show `args` is not null and another `@NotNull` to show the members of `args` are also not null? I need to annotate them both at the same time. If `args` is a `java.util.List`, I can use `@NotNull List<@NotNull String>`. But `args` is an array -- and I don't know how does the annotation affect on the type of `args`.

Comment: "*My question is, is `@Foo` annotated on `String` or `String[]`?*" - Neither nor. It annotates `args`. Just like `@Foo` does not annotate `Stream`, but `foo`.

Comment: Does the first line even compile for you?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Yes, it works.

Comment: @Turing85 What if I want to use `@NotNull` to annotate the member of `args`? How can I achieve that?

Comment: @ice1000 you're right, it needs `@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)` but it's possible

Comment: @Turing85 Do you mean `@NotNull @NotNull String[]`? What if I need a `@NotNull` to show `args` is not null and another `@NotNull` to show the members of `args` are also not null? I need to annotate them both at the same time.

Comment: @ice1000 I do not think that this is possible with arrays.

Comment: That's really a pity... Anyway thanks @Turing85

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possible answers to the question "in `@Foo String[] args`, what is `@Foo` annotating?".

- If `@Foo` is a **type annotation** (that is, the definition of `Foo` is meta-annotated with `@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)`), then `@Foo` applies to the element type `String`, and you have declared an array of `@Foo String`.
- If `Foo` is a **declaration annotation** (its definition is not meta-annotated with `@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)`), then `@Foo` applies to the entire declaration `String[] args`.  This is uncommon for formal paremeters.

In that position, the `@Foo` annotation cannot refer to the array type `String[]`.

(The other response gives a useful answer for `@NonNull` in particular, but doesn't answer the original question.)

Answer (score 7):

Defining `@NonNull` before the array level seems to do the trick (for the Checker Framework at least):

```
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull;

class App {
    void foo() {
        String @NonNull [] bar;
        bar = null; // NOK
        bar = new String[1];
        bar[0] = null; // NOK
    }
}
```

Results in two errors (cf. [live demo](http://eisop.uwaterloo.ca/live/#mode=display&code=import+org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull%3B%0A%0Aclass+App+%7B%0A++++void+foo()+%7B%0A++++++++String+%40NonNull+%5B%5D+bar%3B%0A++++++++bar+%3D+null%3B+//+NOK%0A++++++++bar+%3D+new+String%5B1%5D%3B%0A++++++++bar%5B0%5D+%3D+null%3B+//+NOK%0A++++%7D%0A%7D&typeSystem=nullness)):

```
| No. | Type  |                                 Description                                 | Line | Column |
|-----|-------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|------|--------|
|   1 | error | Error: [assignment.type.incompatible] incompatible types in assignment.     |    6 |     15 |
|     |       |   found   : null                                                            |      |        |
|     |       |   required: @Initialized @NonNull String @UnknownInitialization @NonNull [] |      |        |
|   2 | error | Error: [assignment.type.incompatible] incompatible types in assignment.     |    8 |     18 |
|     |       |   found   : null                                                            |      |        |
|     |       |   required: @Initialized @NonNull String                                    |      |        |
```

To answer your actual question, see the [specification, §9.7.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.4):

> ```
> @C int @A [] @B [] f;
> ```
>
> *`@A` applies to the array type `int[][]`, `@B` applies to its component type
>   `int[]`, and `@C` applies to the element type `int`.*

So `@Foo String[] args` is actually annotating `String` (read as: a possibly null array of non-null strings).

Comment: Thanks, your answer has perfectly resolved my problem!